# Show second to last item in Influx query (or ignore last)

Tags: database, sorting, select, grafana, influxdb

I am using Grafana to show the number of entries added to the database every minute, and I would like to display the last recent fully counted value.

If I give the following command:

```
SELECT count("value") FROM "numSv" GROUP BY time(1m)

1615904700000000000 60
1615904760000000000 60
1615904820000000000 60
1615904880000000000 60
1615904940000000000 36
```

Grafana is going to display the last entry, which is still in the process of counting. How can I display the n[-1] entry, which has been fully counted?

Otherwise, how do I ask Influx to give me the same results excluding the last dataset?

P.S.: Using WHERE time > now() - 60s, etc... doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "magic" Grafana time range math and select dashboard time range from `now-1m/m` to `now-1m/m`. That generates an absolute time range, which refers to last fully counted minute. Query is then standard with `$timeFilter` Grafana macro:

```
SELECT count("value") FROM "numSv" WHERE $timeFilter
```